# Kentico 11 Validation Online-Form not working with Custom Widget

Tags: widget, kentico

I have create new webpart and widget for insert content via Page Tab. In my code I using asp:Literal for to get content from widget.

a issue when I insert Online-Form into content editor my widget not display validation.

```
/// <summary>
/// Content
/// </summary>
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("Content"), LiteralCotent.Text);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue("Content", Content);
            LiteralCotent.Text = value;
            LiteralCotent.EnableViewState = ControlsHelper.ResolveDynamicControls(this);
        }
    }
```

any idea?

Thanks, Vuthy

Comment: which validations are you talking about here? For widget you can set the validations on field level from admin panel. The code which you have shared is just a get set for property.

Answer (score 0):

We can set the validation for online-forms.
Steps to set validation :-
1. Goto Forms module ==> click on your form.
2. Goto fields tab & select the which filed you want to apply the validation.
3. Right side it shows the properties of the filed and validation also.
4. If existing validation rules are apt your requirement go with it otherwise go with the regular expression.
Please refer to this [link](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-form-validation)